# SQLite select 5 random users that have similar values

Tags: sqlite, node-sqlite3

So this is what I have right now and this works perfectly fine for what I needed before:

`SELECT hex, firewall FROM users order by RANDOM() LIMIT 5`

It gets 5 random users from the database and lets me see the hex and firewall. Pretty simple.

However now I'd like to get 5 random users from the table who ALSO have a sum (bypasser+firewall+decryptor+encryptor+antivirus+spam) of ${variable} +- 5

I still, only need to select the firewall and hex. However I need the users that are shown at random to have bypasser+firewall+decryptor+encryptor+antivirus+spam (with a range of +-5) of a number I give it. For example: If I passed "6" through as the ${variable} I'd need to get 5 random users in which the sum of their firewall+bypasser+decryptor+encryptor+antivirus+spam is 6 +- 5 (1 to 11)

Here is what my sqlite table looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need a `WHERE` clause in your query:

```
SELECT hex, firewall 
FROM users
WHERE ABS(firewall + bypasser + decryptor + encryptor + antivirus + spam - ?) <= 5
ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 5
```

Replace the placeholder `?` with the value of `${variable}`.

Answer (score 0):

I found a better solution to what I was trying to accomplish by taking the average instead of the sum:

```
SELECT   hex, firewall 
FROM     users 
WHERE    (firewall+bypasser+decryptor+encryptor+antivirus+spam) / 6 
BETWEEN  ${userAvg - 10} 
  AND    ${userAvg + 5} 
order by RANDOM() 
LIMIT    5
```

Took me a while, but I kind of understand SQL now after a day of working with it. my brain hurts.

Comment: This is not a better solution. It is a solution for a different problem that has nothing to do with the question you asked.